# Raphael JS - get element by id, move that element to the top

Tags: javascript, raphael

I a missing something obvious with Raphael JS. I am a) looping through an array, b) drawing circles from the values, c) creating text overlays, and d) setting up listeners in Raphael.

What I am struggling with is actions in the listeners. Specifically, how do I get an element by its id, then do something like move it to the top.

Source at JSFiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/NPks2/3/

I would expect this to work, but it does not. Can you help?

```
// this happening while looping through an object
var p = paper.circle(x_coord, y_coord, diameter)
    .data("i", i)
    .attr({"fill": "90-"+fillColorStart+":5-"+fillColorEnd+":95","fill-opacity": 0.5})
    .glow({color: "#4b4b4b", width: 7})

    paper.text(x_coord, y_coord, opportunityTitle)
    .data("text_id", i+"text")
    .attr({ "font-size": 16, "font-family": fontFamily, "fill":fontColor});

    paper.text(x_coord, title_y_coord, ideasCount)
    .attr({ "font-size": 27, "font-family": fontFamily, "fill":fontColor});


// loop is over, listeners are waiting
paper.forEach(function(element) {
    element.mouseover(function() {
            c = elem_id = this.data("i");    
        t = p.getById(elem_id"+text);

        c.toFront();
        t.toFront();
    });
});
```

Comment: it seems there's a redundant double quote in `t = p.getById(elem_id"+text)`. is that a typo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add:

```
this.toFront();
```

to your element.mouseover function:

I updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NPks2/4/):